# PHP, Tokenizer, find all the arguments of the function

Tags: php, tokenize

Help me find all the arguments of the function "funcname" using the function token_get_all() in the source code. It sounds simple, but there are many special options, such as arrays as parameters or call static methods as parameters. Maybe there's a simple universal solution?

UPD:

I need the function arguments passed when you call it. Get them to be at an external analysis of the file. For example, there is a php-file:

```
<?php
funcname('foo');
funcname(array('foo'), 'bar');
```

The analyzer should begin as follows:

```
$source = file_get_contents('source.php');
$tokens = token_get_all($source);
...
```

As a result, need to get a list like this:

```
[0] => array('foo'),
[1] => array(array('foo'), 'bar')
```

Comment: Hi Anton,  I have a similar issue for static analysis of localisation functions.  Did you ever find a solid solution to this?

Comment: Does PHP-Parser ( https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser ) can help?

Answer (score 5):

Rather than using a tokenizer, use reflection. In this case, use [`ReflectionFunction`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionfunction.php):

```
function funcname ($foo, $bar) {

}

$f = new ReflectionFunction('funcname');
foreach ($f->getParameters() as $p) {
    echo $p->getName(), "\n";
}
```

This outputs

```
foo
bar
```

You can also use this class and related classes (such as `ReflectionParameter`) to find out more information about a function and its parameters, such as whether a parameter is optional and what its default value is.

Comment: Thank you. I incorrectly described the problem, updated the topic.